# Pipelined function on oracle almost aways gives invalid state

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

The following code runs fine:

```
create type my_tab_type is object
(tipo char(2), nome varchar2(500), cpf_cnpj varchar2(1), 
  ie varchar2(1), ie_dev varchar2(1))
/

create type my_tab_type_coll is table of my_tab_type;
/

create or replace function get_some_data (p_val in number) 
return my_tab_type_coll pipelined is
begin
  FOR i in (select '1a' tipo,'a' nome,'b' cpf_cnpj,'c' ie,'d' ie_dev  from dual where 1=0) loop
    pipe row(my_tab_type(i.tipo,i.nome,i.cpf_cnpj,i.ie,i.ie_dev));
  end loop;
  return;
end;
/


SELECT * FROM table(get_Some_Data(1));
```

This code doesn't

```
create type my_tab_type is object
(tipo char(2), nome varchar2(500), cpf_cnpj varchar2(1), 
  ie varchar2(1), ie_dev varchar2(1))
/

create type my_tab_type_coll is table of my_tab_type;
/

create or replace function get_some_data (p_val in number) 
return my_tab_type_coll pipelined is
begin
  FOR i in (select '1a' tipo,'a' nome,'b' cpf_cnpj,'c' ie,'d' ie_dev  from person  where 1=0) loop
    pipe row(my_tab_type(i.tipo,i.nome,i.cpf_cnpj,i.ie,i.ie_dev));
  end loop;
  return;
end;
/


SELECT * FROM table(get_Some_Data(1));
```

I have only changed from where data is coming from (or not, since its where 1=0)
The first case is from dual and runs like a charm
The second case is from person and gives the error `invalid state`

Any table that is put in the query that isn't dual, gives invalid state

Why?

Comment: After creating the second function, which is apparently compiling with warnings/errors for you and you're ignoring that message, do `show errors` to see what's wrong. Or query the `user_errors` view. It can only really be ORA-00942. If the `person` table exists then that also works, so do you actually have that table in your schema? If it's in another schema do you have privileges on it granted directly or through a role?

Comment: i didnt had the privileges. thanks. Now i can debug better.